# Rock Paper Scissors (Python) - enumerating a list, pulling values based on logic, and comparing those to the original list

Tags: python, list

So the question is that there are N number of people in a line, playing rock paper scissors. Each person but me can only use one type of hand, represented as

`['P', 'R', 'S', 'P']`   for N hands.

I can use any type and am at some arbitrary position A.

I need to be able to know what position I have to play against once the list reaches me, so N-A-1. This means I have to iterate over the list, figure out a winner for each match up, and compare that result with the next position in the list, until it gets to me.

What I've tried doing is creating an empty array of `winners` and then enumerating through the given list.

Once there is a value for winners, it is compared to the value of the next index in the enumeration of the list.

I've currently got no solution for what happens when I get to the last iteration, but currently my problem is that I'm getting an empty list as an output for winners.

Any help on best practices for this type of logic with lists would be awesome, I haven't been able to find anything that fits.

Code:

```py
def previous_and_next(n, a, formations):
    positions = list(formations)
    print(positions)

    winners = []
    print(winners)    

    for i, pos in enumerate(positions):
        nex = pos[i + 1]
        if not winners:
            if pos == 'R' and nex == 'P':
                winners.append(nex)   
            elif pos == 'R' and nex == 'S':
                winners.append(pos)
            elif pos == 'R' and nex == 'R':
                continue
            elif pos == 'P' and nex == 'S':
                winners.append(nex)
            elif pos == 'P' and nex == 'R':
                winners.append(pos)
            elif pos == 'P' and nex == 'P':
                continue
            elif pos == 'S' and nex == 'R':
                winners.append(nex)
            elif pos == 'S' and nex == 'P':
                winners.append(pos)
            elif pos == 'S' and nex == 'S':
                continue
        if nex < len(positions-1):
            if  winners[-1:]    == 'P' and nex == 'R' or nex == 'P':
                continue
            elif winners[-1:]  == 'R' and nex == 'R' or nex == 'S':
                continue
            elif winners[-1:]  == 'S' and nex == 'P' or nex == 'S':
                continue
            elif winners[-1:]  == 'P' and nex == 'S':
                winners.append(pos)
            elif winners[-1:]  == 'R' and nex == 'P':
                winners.append(pos)
            elif winners[-1:]  == 'S' and nex == 'R':
                winners.append(pos)




def main():
    previous_and_next(5,0,'PRSP')

main()
```

Comment: `winners[:]` will return a copy of the list, not sure what you are wanting to compare here. `if winners[:]  == 'FOO'` is comparing a list to a string

Comment: `nex = i + 1` nex is an integer, you're comparing it to a string too but that's never going to match

Comment: Thanks for the help, I haven't touched python in a while and so I've lost a lot of the memory of syntax. I've updated to winners[-1:], the idea being that I want to compare the next iteration to the current winning hand.

Comment: Could you try and explain the prompt one more time? I've read your post and your code but it still isn't clear to me. Is player 0 playing against player 1, and player 1 against player 2, and so on? What do you mean by "when the list reaches me"? Why do you need to know the winners of all matches held between people who came before you? None of this is clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't respond to my comment asking for clarification. I'm posting an answer now which I will modify later once you've explained the prompt again. I've tried to interpret your original post into a sequence of steps (as I have understood them). Please let me know if this is the program flow you are going for:

```
    ['R', 'S', 'P', 'R', '?']
      0    1    2    3    A

1.) Player 0 and Player 1 play rock paper scissors.
    Player 0 wins, because (R)ock beats (S)cissors.

2.) The previous winner (Player 0) and Player 2 play rock paper scissors.
    Player 2 wins, because (P)aper beats (R)ock.

3.) The previous winner (Player 2) and Player 3 play rock paper scissors.
    Player 2 wins, because (P)aper beats (R)ock.

4.) The previous winner (Player 2) and Player A (you) play rock paper scissors.
    You must play (S)cissors to beat (P)aper
```

EDIT - Additional question: Let's say we have:

```
['S', 'R', 'P', 'S', 'S', 'R', 'P']
  0    1    2    3    4    5    6
```

1. Rock beats Scissors
2. Paper beats Rock
3. Scissors beats Paper
4. Scissors and Scissors TIE

Now that we have arrived at the first tie, what happens exactly? You said that the two scissors are eliminated from the game, but how does the game continue? Do we jump to the Rock at index 5, and have them play against Paper at index 6, OR do we jump to the last valid winner (which in this example was Paper at index 2), and have them play against Rock at index 5? Thanks for your further information.

EDIT - Here is a solution I came up with. To figure out how many hand changes you need to make, you need to sum the number of hand changes needed to beat the winning hand before you (which is either 0 or 1), and the number of hand changes you need to make to beat all hands after you. I'm sure there's a cuter way of doing it:

```
from enum import Enum


class Hand(Enum):
    Rock = 0
    Paper = 1
    Scissors = 2


class Game:

    def __init__(self, hands):
        self.hands = hands

    @staticmethod
    def get_winner_from_hands(hands):

        # This function, given a list of hands, will return the winning hand in that list.
        # In other words, it returns the type of hand that the winning player had in that list of hands.
        # This is especially useful if we pass in a sublist/slice of the whole list (the slice)...
        # ...would contain all hands before the player whose number of hand changes we are...
        # ... interested in computing.

        # This 'stack' list is meant to simulate the stack data-structure.
        # It's a stack of hands where, at any given moment, the most recent...
        # ...winning hand is on top of the stack.
        stack = []

        while hands:
            # While there are hands left to be matched up
            if not stack:
                stack.append(hands.pop(0))

            # 'top_hand' represents the hand that's on top of the stack...
            # ...(the most recent winning hand).
            top_hand = stack[-1]
            try:
                next_hand = hands.pop(0)
            except IndexError:
                # There were no more hands left to process.
                # This happens when we just had a tie (and cleared the stack as a result)...
                # ...but there was only one more hand left to process (and you need at least two for a match).
                # This can also happen if the 'hands' list that was passed in only had one hand in it.
                break
            winner = Game.get_match_winner(top_hand, next_hand)
            if winner is None:
                # It's a tie.
                stack.clear()
            elif winner is next_hand:
                stack.append(next_hand)

        try:
            # Return the last winning hand on the stack.
            return stack.pop()
        except IndexError:
            # If the stack was empty, there was no winning hand because of a tie.
            return None

    def get_number_of_hand_changes(self, hand_index):
        # Returns the number of times the player at index 'hand_index'...
        # ...must change their hand type in order to beat all other hands...
        # ...before them and after them.

        hands_before = self.hands[:hand_index]
        hands_after = self.hands[hand_index+1:]

        hand = self.hands[hand_index]

        # Who is the winner before us?
        previous_winner = Game.get_winner_from_hands(hands_before)

        if previous_winner is None or hand is Game.get_winning_hand(previous_winner):
            # All hands before 'hand_index' do not contribute to the total number of...
            # ...hand changes the player needs to make, either because of...
            # ...a tie, or we would beat the previous winner without changing hands anyway.
            hand_changes = 0
        else:
            # We either tied with, or didn't beat the previous winner.
            hand_changes = 1
            # Pick the hand we need to beat the previous winner.
            hand = Game.get_winning_hand(previous_winner)

        # This stack of hands represents the hand changes we need to make...
        # ...to beat the hands that come after us. At any given moment, the...
        # ...hand on top of this stack is the last hand change we've had to make.
        stack = []
        hands = hands_after

        while hands:
            top_hand = hand if not stack else stack[-1]
            next_hand = hands.pop(0)
            if top_hand is not Game.get_match_winner(top_hand, next_hand):
                stack.append(Game.get_winning_hand(next_hand))

        # The total number of hand changes we've had to make is...
        # ...the sum of the number of hand changes we've had to make to...
        # ...beat the winning hand before us, and  the number of hand changes...
        # we've had to make to beat the hands after us.
        return hand_changes + len(stack)

    @staticmethod
    def get_winning_hand(hand):
        # Given a hand, return the hand that beats it.
        return Hand((hand.value + 1) % len(Hand))

    @staticmethod
    def get_match_winner(hand_a, hand_b):
        # This function simulates a single Rock-Paper-Scissors match between two hands.
        # It returns the winning hand, or None if it's a tie.
        if hand_a is hand_b:
            return None
        return [hand_a, hand_b][Game.get_winning_hand(hand_a) is hand_b]


def main():

    hand_index = 4

    hands = [
        Hand.Rock,
        Hand.Scissors,
        Hand.Paper,
        Hand.Rock,
        Hand.Paper,  # hand_index
        Hand.Paper,
        Hand.Paper,
        Hand.Scissors,
        Hand.Rock
    ]

    game = Game(hands)

    hand_changes = game.get_number_of_hand_changes(hand_index)

    print(hand_changes)

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Apologies for not answering earlier I was asleep, but you have hit the nail on the head, with one caviat - if they tie, both players are out. When the winner of that flow reaches ``['?']``, then it "has reached me". The final goal of the game is to figure out how many times you have to change hands to win the tournament (the list represents all the people playing) so in order to do that, I must know what hand I'm starting out with when playing against people behind me.

Comment: Hi MjBVala, thanks for clarifying. Good to know that I was on the right track. I'll update my answer with an additional question.

Comment: I really appreciate you asking for clarification, it will help me do a better job of explaining down the line. The answer to your question is that we jump to the Rock at index 5.

Comment: Thanks. I've made another edit to my post with my solution.

Comment: Right answer, thank you so much! I tried giving you credit via upvote but I'm still not sure how it works so if It didn't and there's something else I can do, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what the question is asking, but it seems that your problem is that you are trying to compare a string to an int. Try `nex = positions[i + 1]` instead of `nex = i + 1`.

Comment: The question I'm asking specifically or what the prompt is? You're right on that, I was just using the index! But now I'm getting the error that ``nex = pos[i + 1]
IndexError: string index out of range``. I believe it has something to do with the last iteration where n +1 will be out of range, but I'm not sure how to implement a check on that.

Comment: Try to iterate through all the positions, except for the last one. You can do that with this code: `for i, pos in enumerate(positions[:-1]):`